# Dynamically including pandoc-transformed texfiles in latex template

Tags: automation, pandoc

I am currently running the following command to populate my latex template.

`pandoc -s  --top-level-division=chapter --template=template.tex metadata.md content/*.md -o frommarkdown.tex`

The content of the  latex-ized *.md files are populating the template via the `$body$` variable.
However this happens verbatim, the `$body$`variable gets in-place substituted with the tex code generated from the md files. This generated a huge latex file with all my thesis chapters in one big file concatenated.

My ideal case would look like that I can `\include` all of the on the fly generated tex-files in my document, allowing me to keep a clean latex document which can come in handy when debugging or altering a larger project (e.g thesis).

I would ideally like to have something like that:

`$for(include-chapters)$
  \include($include-chapters$)
$endfor$`

My hunch was now to achieve this with a two step solution by first generating standalone tex files per *.md file (without the usage of a template). Then I would like to dynamically include these generated tex files in my main tex "template".

Can this be achieved with pandoc or do i need to write a custom shell script for this?

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved with pure pandoc. You can try pandoc-discuss for help building a custom filter for that. Have you considered working in your thesis entirely in markdown/pandoc instead of going back and forth to tex?

Answer (score 3):

I don't grasp what you are exactly trying to do but you can modify the template and make it include tex files.

1. Get the latex template and save it to `template.tex`: `pandoc -D latex > template.tex`
2. Open the template file and add the following code snippet below `$body$`:

   ```
   $for(include-chapters)$
     \include{$include-chapters$}
   $endfor$
   ```
3. Now you can add the files you want to include to `metadata.md`:

   ```
   ---
   include-chapters:
   - content/chapter1
   - content/chapter2
   ---
   ```
4. Run `pandoc`:

   ```
   pandoc -s -S --top-level-division=chapter \
          --template=template.tex \
          metadata.md -o frommarkdown.tex
   ```

Those steps will result in:

> ```
>  \begin{document}
>
>    \include{content/chapter1}
>    \include{content/chapter2}
>
>  \end{document}
> ```

---

Still I don't recommend doing this. There are very powerful tools out there, which can do more and better, e.g. [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))